# implement toString for enum typeScript

Tags: typescript

I would like to know if it is possible to redefine toString() for an enum.

Here is my enum:

```js
enum Person{
  FOO = 10,
  FAA = 1,
  FII = 2
}
```

I want to redefine toString so that when Person.FOO.toString() is called, that return "FOO". Is that possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look at the compiled javascript for your code:

```
var Person;
(function (Person) {
    Person[Person["FOO"] = 10] = "FOO";
    Person[Person["FAA"] = 1] = "FAA";
    Person[Person["FII"] = 2] = "FII";
})(Person || (Person = {}));
```

You'll notice that `Person.FOO` is just a number (`10` to be specific), so the only way to override the `toString` for it requires you to override it for all numbers, and you probably don't want that.

If you're looking for the name of the enum (instead of the ordinal) then you can simply do this:

```
console.log(Person[Person.FOO]); // "FOO"
```

Comment: Where should I write this? I tried to copy and paste your code, but typescript complains and said `Duplicate identifier of Person`

Comment: Which code have you tried to copy? This part: `Person[Person.FOO]` ?

Comment: I copied this in my .ts file: `(function (Person) {
    Person[Person["FOO"] = 10] = "FOO";
    Person[Person["FAA"] = 1] = "FAA";
    Person[Person["FII"] = 2] = "FII";
})(Person || (Person = {}));` is it wrong?

Comment: Oh, no no. That's the compiled javascript for the code **you posted**. There's no need for that. I only posted it so that it will be clear why what you're asking for can't be done.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible. Enum is not type which could be extended in JavaScript/TypeScript. I recommend you to write simple method/function which will expect Person as parameter and do what you need.